# SQL Server index - ideas?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, indexing

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    c.violatorname
FROM 
    dbo.crimecases AS c,
    dbo.people AS p
WHERE 
    REPLACE(c.violatorname, ' ', '') = CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(p.firstname, p.secondname), p.thirdname), p.lastname);
```

The query is very slow, I need to create an index on `violatorname` column with replace function. Any ideas?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The query is slow because you are using functions on your predicates.  This does not allow SQL to use the statistics to create a good plan.  It has to scan every single row in order to figure out what the value of REPLACE is on that column as well as the CONCAT on the other side of the equal sign.  Go with the computed column as was suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to add `computed columns` and create `index` on it.

```
ALTER TABLE crimecases
  ADD violatornameProcessed AS Replace(violatorname, ' ', '') PERSISTED 

ALTER TABLE people
  ADD fullName AS Concat(firstname, secondname, thirdname, lastname) PERSISTED
```

`Persisted` will store the computed data on the disk instead of computing every time. Now create index on it.

```
CREATE INDEX Nix_crimecases_violatornameProcessed
  ON crimecases (violatornameProcessed)
  include (violatorname)

CREATE INDEX Nix_people_fullName
  ON people (fullName)
```

Query can be written like

```
SELECT c.violatorname
FROM   dbo.crimecases AS c
       INNER JOIN dbo.people AS p
               ON c.violatornameProcessed = p.fullName
```